# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810

Tags: macos, homebrew, java

Downloaded and installed the AirStream application, and when I launched it nothing happens. In `Terminal` the output is

```
$ open /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app.
```

This seems to be a Java stub/launcher

```
$ file /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub 
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
Lees-MacBook-Pro:Casks hanxue$ oprn /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

When I manually run it

```
$ open /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

This is the result

```
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub ; exit;
$ /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/airstream/latest/AirStream.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub ; exit;
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
[JavaAppLauncher Error] JNI_CreateJavaVM() failed, error: -1
logout
```

Java is properly installed, and I have other Java applications running without a hitch. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 8):

The error occurs because JVM failed to launch - the Java application itself has been hardcoded to load `libserver.dylib`. This file exist for Java 1.6 and older, but not for Java 1.7 and above.

### Workaround

Create the directory structure and symlink from `libjvm.dylib` to `libserver.dylib`

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
```

*Note that this is specific to JDK 1.8.0 update 5. The paths will need to be updated in three places for future versions.*

### Solution

Modify the Java application's code so that it will not look for libserver.dylib. You should really not hard-code the path to JVM. Instead, use `/usr/libexec/java_home` if you need the path of JVM in OSX.